# Update SVG element position

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, position, jquery-animate

The very basic approach to move SVG image to another place is

```
elementToMove.animate({svgTransform: 'translate(100, -30)'}, 1000, "swing", function(){ console.log('Done!'); } );
```

But this is somehow fake, when I will check this with

```
elementToMove.getBoundingClientRect()
```

The result X,Y coordinates will be the same as before (as it would never move).

I need to track position of moved (translated?) elements, but I don't really know how to make it.

The only way I can imagine is to make separate class for moved elements and make some autocalculated position fields whenever move method would be called, but this is terrible idea as I already made a lot of code.

Comment: Can you create a sample on jsfiddle?

Comment: why not using canvas instead of svg? I think with canvas you can do it, better.